# how to get local notification of our app as "Open Image with our app" when taking screen shots outside our app holding "sleep/wake" & "home" button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, screenshot, localnotification

I need to have local notification of my app "Open Screenshot with our app"  when  a screen shot is taken while using other apps in ios like "whatsapp" and when taking screen shot by holding "sleep/wake" & "home" button, there should be a local notification from my app to open the screen shotted image with my app like "Stich&share" in android.. Is it possible in Ios(My app may run in background) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do with [UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1622966-uiapplicationuserdidtakescreensh)

```
let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshot,
object: nil,
queue: mainQueue) { notification in
        // executes after screenshot
}
```

Comment: @Santhosh This will work when our app is in foreground but when our app is running in background, Does this possible when our app is in background and where to call this method, if it works in background ?